# UITableView loading data into wrong cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Below I am trying to load data into a UITableView and every time the data ends up either in the wrong cell or duplicated into cells it should never had access to.  I  have cut out a lot of extra code and am still running into this problem. I think I am missing something fundamental about UITableViews.

```
    func setUpFeedTable() {

                self.tableFeed.isScrollEnabled = true

                for i in 0 ..< allDictionary.count {


                    let dictionary = allDictionary[i]


                    if dictionary?["type"]! != nil {
                        let l = i
                        print("text", l)
                        self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: l, section: 0))?.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                        self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: l, section: 0))?.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1
                        self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: l, section: 0))?.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 1

                        //self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))?.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
                        self.editProfileButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                        //self.tableFeed.reloadData()
                        //self.tableFeed.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: l, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: 0)!)

                        self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: l, section: 0))?.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2, width: 100, height: 100)

                        self.tableTextOverLays(i: l, type: Int((dictionary?["type"])! as! NSNumber))

                        //self.tableFeed.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: l, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation(rawValue: 0)!)

                        self.tableFeed.reloadDate()
                    }

                    else if (dictionary?["type_"] as! String) == "Image" {
                        print("image", i)

                    }
                    else {
                        print("video")
                    }



                }



            }

            func tableTextOverLays(i: Int, type: Int){
                if type == 0{
                    print("saw type 0", i)
                    self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))?.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Geo-fence-50")
                }

                else if type == 1 {
                    self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))?.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Happy-50")
                }

                else if type == 2 {
                    self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))?.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Information-50")
                }

                else if type == 3 {
                    self.tableFeed.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))?.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Home-50")
                }
            }
```

Update:  I have edited my code and things are working far better (so thank you!)  but I am now running into the issue of a images being place both into the first two cells and then the 4th and 5th cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == self.table {
            return users2.count

        }
        else {
            //print("married barry", tableFeedCount)
            return tableFeedCount
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == self.table {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.users2[indexPath.row].name
            return cell
        }
        else {
            //print("working?")
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as UITableViewCell
            let dictionary = allDictionary[indexPath.row]


            if dictionary?["type"]! != nil {
                cell.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
                cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 1


                cell.imageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2, width: 100, height: 100)

                self.tableTextOverLays(i: indexPath.row, type: Int((dictionary?["type"])! as! NSNumber), cell: cell)

            }

            else if (dictionary?["type_"] as! String) == "Image" {
                print("image")

            }
            else {
                print("video")
            }


            return cell
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not trying to leverage the `tableViewDataSource` protocol?

Comment: Yes, you're using the wrong method. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns the formatted cell that already exists at the requested index. Cells are dumb containers that get reused/refilled as you scroll through the list, so you can't set properties individually like this. Initial cell formatting happens in `dequeueReusableCell...` Here you set labels, images, cell types. It creates cells for each index in the `dataSource`; no loop req'd.
 Header/footer cells use separate methods as well. Suggest looking into tutorials about how to use UITableView, create custom UITableViewCell subclasses, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you'r trying to set UITableviewCells metadata requesting cell's to the tableView, Cells are reused in UITableView protocol method cellforRowAtIndexPath and that is why you see duplicates or metadata in other cells.

What you need to do is set the metadata of each cell in cellforRowAtIndexPath method.

For example if you have an array with info like this

```
let metadata = ["title1", "title2", "title3"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return metadata.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let title = metadata[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = title
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't right to populate a `TableView` like that.
Each `TableView` must be related to a `DataSource` or to a `UITableViewDelegate`, and this, for example, should implement methods such as `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

For instance:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var myStrings = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        }
        return myStrings.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseId", for: indexPath)
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "This is the row in the first section"
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = myStrings[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```